# PHP return object from SOAP

Tags: php

How to store SOAP returned value in PHP?

My PHP code using SOAP.

```
    <?php
        $client = new SoapClient("http://rscnagahrd/OracleWS/Oracle.asmx?WSDL");
        $result = $client->getFoods();
        echo $result;
    ?>
```

When I try to run the application I get the error:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in C:\apache\htdocs\food.php on line 4

I am doing this so that I could later parse the xml code:

```
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
$dom->loadXML($result);
$params = $dom->getElementsByTagName('FOOD_ID');
    foreach ($params as $param) {
    echo $param -> nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Soapclient` object already has parsed the XML to a response structure (`var_dump($result)` and see). If you want to store it as a string, you'd have make it a string again somehow (`serialize()` if only PHP code needs to read it, `json_encode()` if you want to make it more language-agnostic are the usual suspects).

If you need to store the *raw* `xml` response, add `array('trace' => true);` as the 2nd parameter in `SoapClient`'s constructor, and call `$client->__getLastRequest();`.

But, if you just want the answer used then & there the `$result` response is already parsed for you.

Comment: Its not the answer I was expecting, but it made sense that I was not asking the right question. Thanks

Comment: Ah, what question did you _mean_ to ask?

Comment: Inside `$result` is an xml name food_name, food_description, etc, how can i extract them and place them into a php variable, debugging in visual studio returns something like: `<Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
<FOOD_ID>
1
</FOOD_ID>
<FOOD_NAME>
Burger
</FOOD_NAME>
<FOOD_DESC>
100% Beef Patty
</FOOD_DESC>
<FOOD_PRICE>
25
</FOOD_PRICE>
</Table>
<Table diffgr:id="Table2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
<FOOD_ID>
2
</FOOD_ID>
<FOOD_NAME>
Coke
</FOOD_NAME>
<FOOD_DESC>
Drinks
</FOOD_DESC>
<FOOD_PRICE>
10
</FOOD_PRICE>
</Table>`

Comment: It depends on whether that is sent as actual xml in the soap response (so you'd acces it something like `foreach($result->Table as $food) echo $food->FOOD_ID.':'.$food->FOOD_NAME`, or as encoded xml (i.e: it will be as a string in some location in the struct, and we need to build in object out of it). If you put the results of `var_dump($result);` up somewhere on pastebin.com or something like that, I could tell you more.

Comment: [var_dum($result)](http://pastebin.com/e3vNbUBg). I have also tried `foreach($result->Table as $food) echo $food->FOOD_ID.':'.$food->FOOD_NAME` but i am getting an error [foreach](http://pastebin.com/sC9ZdMRL)

Comment: I've also tried [different array index](http://pastebin.com/s1iCDGsx), but error:  `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\apache\htdocs\ordering.php on line 31`  `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\apache\htdocs\ordering.php on line 31`   `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\apache\htdocs\ordering.php on line 31`  `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\apache\htdocs\ordering.php on line 31`

Comment: You have double-encoded xml in the response (i.e.: xml embedded as encoded string in the actual Soap response. While this is not perfect, we can work around it by making a _new_ simplexmlelement of it based on the _string_ in `any`, like so for instance: `$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($result['getFoodsResult']['any']); foreach($xml->Table as $table){..etc..}`

Comment: BTW: from your `var_dump` result, I gather you examine the output _in a browser window_. While you can do this, try to always look at the _source_ of that document rather then the HTML rendering of it (as now I can't see a lot, or actually any, `<tag>`'s due to the rendering engine hiding them.

Comment: I'm still getting error `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\apache\htdocs\ordering.php on line 29` when using `newSimpleXMLElement`. I tried converting it to string with `$result = (string)$result;` but getting error `Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in C:\apache\htdocs\ordering.php on line 28`. Generating the returned xml from visual studio, it get this [xml return](http://pastebin.com/cXbhaiug)

Comment: This becomes a bit to convoluted for help in comments, however, I'll give it a shot: (1) Can you confirm for me that `$result['getFoodsResult']['any']` is a _string_ with that XML in it? (2) If you create a simplexmlelement with  `new SimpleXMLElement($result['getFoodsResult']['any']);`, the `Table`'s seem to be in `foreach($xml->NewDataSet->Table as $table)`, does that work? (If not, I'd be interested in the `var_dump($xml);` output again. It may be a namespace issue, check this site for answers for simplexml+namespaces).